# How to conditionally format columns pertaining to a cell value

Tags: python, pandas, excel-formula, xlsxwriter, pandas-styles

I'm trying to color cells within `Column J` a yellow color where it's cell value is `N`.

I'm able to achieve this but I also want to color the corresponding cells in columns `H` & `I` when `Column J` is `N` and am having difficulty doing so.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can implement this?

This is my code so far:

```
     
import pandas as pd

filePath = r"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Match\\"
parameters = 'Transactions.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(filePath + parameters,usecols="A:EN")

with pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Match\\Compare_Matches.xlsx", 
engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    workbook = writer.book
    df.to_excel(writer)
    worksheet = workbook.worksheets()[0]

format_yellow = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFFF00'})

worksheet.conditional_format('J1:J13630', 
                                {'type': 'text',
                                'criteria': 'containing',
                                'value':   'N',
                                'format':   format_yellow,})
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you probably need a formula type conditional format. Here is a simple example based on yours:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'],
                   'Data2': [100, 200, 300, 200, 150, 300, 450],
                   'Data3': [100, 200, 300, 200, 150, 300, 450]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Compare_Matches.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

# Create a format for the conditional format.
format_yellow = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFFF00'})

# Apply a conditional format to the required cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format(1, 1, max_row, max_col,
                             {'type': 'formula',
                              'criteria': '=$B2="N"',
                              'format': format_yellow})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Note, the important part of the formula is `$B2` where the `$B` makes it an absolute reference to column B only and `2` is a relative reference which change with the row.

In general it is best to figure out the conditional format that you want in Excel first and then transfer it to XlsxWriter.